# How to set gradient style to paint object?

Tags: android, android-canvas, gradient

The code for drawing an arrow with *Style: Fill* is given below:

```
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#bdc0dc"));
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, paint);
```

And the output I obtain is this :

[image]

Now what I want do is set style to Gradient(Style.gradient not present in android...) to obtain the arrow similar to the image given below :

[image]

How do i do it ? I tried adding style in style.xml but was unable to add gradient there as it accepts item as parameter..

Answer (score 130, accepted):

use the code below..

```
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, paint);
```

Comment: Note that this also works for TextPaint, e.g., `paint.setShader(...`

Answer (score 14):

If you want more than one color:

```
// Gradient Shade colors distribution setting uniform for now
private val positions = null //floatArrayOf(0f, 0.3f, 0.6f)

// Gradient Shade colors
private val colors = intArrayOf(
        ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                R.color.divider_gradient_start_color),
        ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                R.color.divider_gradient_center_color),
        ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                R.color.divider_gradient_end_color))
```

in OnDraw()

```
// Add Shader
gradientPaint.shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f, measuredWidth.toFloat(),0f, 
                colors, 
                positions,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)

canvas.drawPath(path, gradientPaint)
```