# How to get color defined in xml in the program

Tags: android

I have a gradient color xml (green_gradient.xml) defined in Res\Color folder.
How can I get it to paint to a bar at custom `View`. For normal green color, I paint like

```
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

But how to replace `Color.GREEN` with `green_gradient.xml` defined in Res\Color folder.

EDIT 1.
My green_gradient.xml is in res\color folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#70c656" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53933f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#70c656"
                android:endColor="#53933f"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53933f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: shows us `green_gradient.xml`

Comment: you have `colors.xml` under which you have resource name `green_gradient`?. Need more info.

Comment: No I have green_gradient.xml in Res\Color. I like to use green_gradient.xml to paint my bar at custom View.

Comment: For xml, I can just easily take it as android:background ="@color/green_gradient". But how to get it in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined GREEN color in your custom color set, you can do

```
<your_context>.getResources().getColor(R.color.GREEN);
```

And if the color is altogether in a different xml having different color states then you can use something like

```
XmlResourceParser parser =context.getResources().getXml(R.color.green_gradient);
ColorStateList colors = null;
try {
    colors = ColorStateList.createFromXml(context.getResources(), parser);
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {            
    e.printStackTrace();        
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

mybutton.setTextColor(colors);
```

Comment: but since you are setting the color to paint, I donot see any method there which takes ColorStateList as input.

Comment: I cant't set ColorStateList colors;  to paint.setColor(colors); I have compile error.

Comment: So you mean, drawing in custom View can't use the color designed in xml.

Comment: my intention is to get gradient color. I think I have to design gradient color again for custom View in the program.

Comment: No, at a bar. android:background is I just present as an example of easiness in xml. I draw the bar on the View and want to paint gradient color.

Comment: @batuman check this if you want to set the gradient color to paint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600805/how-to-set-gradient-style-to-paint-object.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `green_gradient.xml` in `drawable` folder and then you can access it programmatically using `R.drawable.green_gradient`. in a layout xml file you can access it as `@drawable/green_gradient`

Comment: op says he has this `green_gradient.xml` and not `colors.xm`

Comment: `colors.xml` is for example. he should replace it with his xml file name (`green_gradient.xml`)

Comment: and also op says `Res\Color`. i don'think your example is what op is asking for.

Comment: yeah my green_gradient is in Res\Color. The xml is shown in the edited version above.