# How to get glow effect in vector images?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I get the glow effect in vector images, just like this:

[image]

I just want a same output like this. I have a bulb and I want a glow effect in that.

Comment: Do you want to generate it programmatically or with other source files ? I don't have a full solution, but I'd say create a gradient from white to transparent and dispatch it on the image the way you want.

Comment: Yes I want it programmatically using seekbar I want to increase the glow effect. But I am using a vector image how can I do in that...@Zekovski

Comment: As you are seeing a semi circular bulb in the above image . I want glow same as that only . The vector image I have i, that is same like the above image.

Comment: Well, as I said, you could create a transparent image you superimpose to this one. On this image, you draw your glow using a circle equation or function, using a gradient from white+transparent to transparent. Here is a SO page similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428973/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-radial-gradient-in-a-canvas